# Maclaurin sereis computation of e in python

Tags: python, series

```
from math import log10, exp

places = int(input('Enter the number of decimal places: '))
one = 10**places
extra = 10**4 

n = 1
term = one * extra 
eee = 0
count = 0

while term > 0:
    eee += term
    count += 1
    term = term // n 
    n += 1

eee = eee // extra

intPart = eee // one

fracPart = eee % one

eee = str(intPart)+'.'+ '0'*(places - (int(log10(fracPart)) + 1))+str(fracPart)

print("""
Python's value of e is:\n%.15f\n
e to %d decimal places is:\n%s\n
The number of terms in the series is %d""" \
% (exp(1), places, eee, count))
```

Questions:

1. What's the reason behind using extra?
2. The first term of the series is 1 but why is term = one * extra?
3. Why is while condition term > 0 ?
4. Logic behind term = term // n

In short problem with understanding the whole code.
Thank you.

Comment: Share some background information before you post the code.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) What's the reason behind using extra?

To keep four extra, hidden decimal places for extra accuracy during the execution of the main loop.  As soon as the main loop ends, the line `eee = eee // extra` throws the four extra places away.

> (2) The first term of the series is 1 but why is term = one * extra?

This is a fixed-point calculation.  What do you know about fixed point?  It requires a *scale,* here represented by `one`.

> (3) Why is while condition `term > 0`?

Because only the first several terms of the series are large enough to matter.  All the late, very small terms can be ignored.  Do you know what the `//` operator does?

Your fourth question should answer itself once the other three answers are understood.